# Domain-joined computer doesn't have Domain network profile

Tags: active-directory

One computer in our domain suddenly shows only Private network and Public network profile. It's probably connected to some update, when also network adapter name changed from "Intel Ethernet Connection ..." to "Intel Ethernet Connection (2) ..."

When the computer leaves the domain, Domain profile is available and selected, but after rejoining the domain, network profile changes back to Private profile, probably upon start of the NLA service. I tried to leave/rejoin the domain, to flush the DNS, reset computer account in AD, rename the computer, googling all around, nothing helped so far.

Comment: OS of the domain member?  Do any of your GPOs specify certain settings to control how the network location awareness machine determines whether or not is on the corporate network?

Comment: Win 10 Enterprise, DC is WS 2016, GPOs don't contain any specific NLA settings. DNS works correctly, DHCP works correctly, ipconfig /all returns everything ok. One more thing - when I remove the computer from the domain, NLA recognizes the network correctly. When the computer joins the domain, for a few seconds it shows correctly the network (it shows domain name), and in a few seconds - probably after NLA service starts - it changes to Private Network and that machine knows nothing about the domain network... Strange, so strange.

Comment: To add more - winlogon also fails, due to "your domain isn't available"...